# Run "AltUnity Tester" to test Unity app in Editor mode: Failed to connect to AltUnity Tester on host: 127.0.0.1 port: 13000?

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, automated-tests, port

This is the first time, I am running **AltUnity Tester** to test an app in Unity 3D, but I got this error:

***OneTimeSetUp: Altom.AltUnityDriver.ConnectionTimeoutException : Failed to connect to AltUnity Tester on host: 127.0.0.1 port: 13000.***

I am testing it in Editor Mode.

My Unity version is: 2019.4

My AltUnityTest version is: 1.7.0 (Jan 25, 2022)

My computer is MacOS.

I am running on Wifi.

---

Here is my test script in **AltUnity Tester**:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Altom.AltUnityDriver;

public class NewAltUnityTest
{
    public AltUnityDriver altUnityDriver;
    //Before any test it connects with the socket
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        altUnityDriver =new AltUnityDriver();
    }

    //At the end of the test closes the connection with the socket
    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        altUnityDriver.Stop();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestStartGame_April_19_2022()
    {
        altUnityDriver.LoadScene("Start");
        
        altUnityDriver.FindObject(By.NAME, "StartButton").Click();

        altUnityDriver.WaitForCurrentSceneToBe("Main");
    }
}
```

Would you please let me know how to fix this error ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you run in editor mode, do you mean that you press "play in editor" from AltUnity Tester Editor. When you start the game you should have a green popup that says: "Waiting for connection port: {the port you set}"

If the popup is not visible that means that the server is not started so the tests don't have anything to connect to.

The tests you posted is correct so you don't have to worry about that.

Another thing could be that the port you are trying to connect is already used, if that is the case just change to another free port.

Might also help if you go through the steps from: https://altom.gitlab.io/altunity/altunitytester/pages/get-started.html